# Elements in Tuple to Tuples in Bag Pig

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-pig

I have the following data below.

```
DUMP a;
(2013-12-25 03:00:55,1899454055,(0958847,090119960,095V987,09518X))
(2013-12-25 03:02:47,1899454055,(09588,090119,0959872P,095189))
(2013-12-25 03:04:00,1899454055,(09588,0901199,09598720P,0951890))
(2013-12-25 03:04:37,1899454055,(0958,0901199,095000P,095189100))
(2013-12-25 03:07:12,3929866522,(0096703))
```

Essentially what I want to do is break out each element in tuple $2, so that there is a row for each element in the tuple for each time stamp.  So row 1 would look like this.

```
(2013-12-25 03:00:55,1899454055,0958847)
(2013-12-25 03:00:55,1899454055,090119960)
(2013-12-25 03:00:55,1899454055,095V987)
(2013-12-25 03:00:55,1899454055,09518X)
```

Now I know the way to do this is convert the tuple to a bag and flatten in.  So, I wrote this Python UDF.

```
@outputSchema("products:{t:(product:chararray)}")
def toBag(t):
     y = [(i,) for i in t]
     return y
```

When I try using this python UDF, I get an unable to open alias error.  However, the a slightly modified version of the UDF works when I am working with integers. (Although, I can't use it here b/c of the alpha characters in the tuple $2)

```
  @outputSchema("ids:bag{t:(id:int)}")
  def splitT(ids):
      x = [(t,) for t in ids]
      return x
```

So, one I'm not sure why the UDF works with int's but not chararray.  Also, I feel like there may be a way to do this without using a UDF..but am not sure where to start with it.  Any suggestions on what may be going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this one was a pretty easy on.. In terms of changing a list of tuples to a bag.

```
 a2 = foreach  generate a time, id_no, TOKENIZE($2);
```

However, I'm still not the deal with the Python UDF's.  If anybody can figure that. I'm all ears.

Comment: If you are searching for STRSPLITTOBAG in older version of pig (like pig 0.12.0), then TOKENIZE will be helpful.